# Best practice - Common child Route for two Parent Routes in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes

In my application, there is a child route which is accessed from two different routes. To explain in detail, there totally 3 routes.

1. Parent
2. Child-1
3. Child-2

From the parent route we can either go directly to Child-2 or Child-1. From Child-1 again we can go to Child-2

Routes Possible are

1. Parent -> Child-1 -> Child-2
2. Parent -> Child-2

Now what's the best method to achieve this ?

So far, my router looks like this

```
this.route('parent', {path: 'parent'},function() {
    this.route('index',{path: '/'});
    this.route('Child-1',{path:'Child-1/id'});
});

this.route('Child-2',{path:'Child-2/id'}, function() {});
```

And in my Parent index template, I've

```
{{#link-to 'Child-1' item disabled=notToChild_1}}
    {{#link-to "Child-2" item disabled=notToChild_2}}
    {{/link-to}}
{{/link-to}}
```

The two boolean variables "notToChild_1" and "notToChild_2" are maintained based on the model.

Is this the right way or Should I use any other method ?

Comment: thumb rule is "Nest your routes if your templates are nested".

Comment: @selvagsz So in this case I should be defining two routes for "Child-2" with the same code ?

Comment: I'm still unclear about your requirements, is your child-2 template resides inside the child-1 template ?

Comment: @selvagsz 
 
Parent can contain many child-2 templates. It can be in two ways. Directly as "child-2" or "Group of child-2" which i named to be "Child-1". So if we choose just child-2 from parent it should go to child-2. Also if we choose the group(child-1) and then child-2 it should still go to child-2.

Comment: In that case, you can treat them as separate routes. Inorder to reuse the code, you can extend one child route and specify the `controllerName` & `templateName` for the routes

Comment: added an example jsbin
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wemeva/1

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to implement this.